# Is there any way with Calabash to Query ALL objects in a screen? (really all)

Tags: calabash

With Calabash, the `Query("all *")` gets about twice as much data as the `query("*")` alone does, but I still have data I cannot read without complex scroll logic.

Is there any good way to get a true 'All' data from a screen without scrolling?

For example, I have a screen with 12 containers each with 5-10 distinct pieces of data.  I need to be able to read my containers to validate the data on the page.

Answer (score 1):

`query` returns all visible views.

`query("all *")` disables the visibility heuristics and returns all views.

Even when using `all`, some part of the view rect must exist within the bounds of the screen.

> without scrolling

If you are using Calabash iOS, you can try the `scroll_to_*` methods which are documented here:

- http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/Calabash/Cucumber/Core.html

`scroll_to_mark` is the most generic - I recommend starting with that method.

Comment: Right, I was hoping for some way of reading the full package of data without scrolling.

Comment: The problem is that some elements might not exist (instances have not been created) until the element is visible in the screen bounds.  This is how UITableView and UICollectionView work.  The secret sauce is that the scroll_to_* methods will create the view instances for table and collection views.