# Can not detect all of element in current active screen with query("*") using calabash console

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I've try to detect all elements in a screen in a APK under test. But, the query("*") always return [] as the result. I try to detect the others screen. It always return all of the elements of the current active screen. But, when i try to detect the screen with UI Automator Viewer provided by android, it returns all of elements of that current screen. What are the possibilities so that it was happened? Or is there any limitation/disability of calabash to detect all elements in a screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way with Calabash to Query ALL objects in a screen? (really all)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616058/is-there-any-way-with-calabash-to-query-all-objects-in-a-screen-really-all)

Comment: No, we have a different case @Lasse  I know how to use query("*") and it really works in others screen page. It returns all of the elements in that screen. But, in one page (chat page), when I execute the query("*"), it just return [], but there was some elements indeed. And i've try detect all of the elements in that screen using UI Automator Viewer it works. But, why calabash gave me negative result?